# Prove linear independence of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

How do I prove that a polynomial is linear independence, I've converted it to a coefficient matrix, but it produces an order of 3x2, then I tried to convert it to reduced row echelon, and managed to get the form, but I still don't really understand and can't draw conclusions if the result is what I get is linear independence or linear dependent.

[The polynomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLKDb.png)

[The result of reduced row echelon form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjTP3.png)

So what i must do next ? or what i can conclude based from the echelon result ?

Comment: This Question is in pretty rough shape.  The images linked can be related to the linear independence of your two polynomials, but the wording of the problem introduces a lot of confusion. Reducing a matrix to row echelon form reveals the *rank* of the matrix, the number of its linearly independent rows.  But you put the polynomial coefficients into *columns* rather than rows without explanation of what you did or why it is justified.  A better Question of this kind is [Linear indepence in polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363610/linear-independence-in-polynomials).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coefficient matrix is wrong It should be
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 &6\\
-2& -4 \\
1 &2 
\end{bmatrix}$$
You seem to be able to apply row echelon reduction with success, it's only that mistake that's stopping you from getting the right answer.
To help you with drawing conclusions, remember what you are doing concretely.
Two vectors $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent if, and only if there are constants $c_1,c_2$ such that $$c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0$$ What you're really doing when doing the matrix of the coefficients and solving the system by means of row reducing is solving for $c_1$ and $c_2$. 
If and only if both your constants are $0$ in the  end are they linearly independent, because then there are no ways of linearly combining those vectors. 
Anyhow, in this case it should be even more obvious that they are linearly dependent. **Hint**: $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0 \iff v_1=\frac{-c_2}{c_1}v_2\iff v_1=cv_2$ (if you can find c such that this equality holds, you prove they are linearly dependent).